# No basis status

Tags: cplex, ampl

when solving a linear problem with Cplex i get the following message:

CPLEX 12.6.2.0: optimal integer solution; objective 8898367.745
798 MIP simplex iterations
0 branch-and-bound nodes
No basis.

What's the meaning of the "no basis" alert?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "No basis" message means that CPLEX didn't provide a feasible basis, you can safely ignore this message. Possible causes of this are discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/EHcfIjzcsU8). My guess is that CPLEX used a heuristic to solve the problem in the root node (because there are 0 branch-and-bound nodes) and didn't resolve the LP with fixed integer variables to get a feasible basis.